# Every page is redirected to 404 page in opencart except Product page

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

Hello guys i m facing a problem please help. I m using OpenCart(Version 1.5.5.1). but from the last day i find that my every poge is redirected to 404 Error page Except Product page.
i couldn't find the reason behind please do some suggestion.

## I have the following code in my .htaccess File.

```
        # Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

#Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
#RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]


### re-direct index.php to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct any parked domain to www of main domain
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.mysite.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up 5 week caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

==============================================================

Comment: What about providing us with the URL of Your store so we could try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What changes did you make on the file?

Comment: My Problems has been Solved now. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a htaccess problem unless your site is working fine without it.

What is the url of a product that is working? Might help to shed some light on the problem.

Paul.